# C# structure code for reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am using XML for first time and a config file.
I am trying to read this config file in order to connect to different connection strings.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <BDD id="aaa">
        <Connexion>
            <MetaDatas>
              <Data id="SOC">Model</Data>
            </MetaDatas>
            <Provider>
              <Name>System.Data.SqlClient</Name>
              <DataSource>10.198.164.169</DataSource>
              <Catalog>xxx</Catalog>
              <User>sa</User>
              <Password>xxx</Password>
            </Provider>
        </Connexion>
    </BDD>
    <BDD id="bbb">
        <Connexion>
            <MetaDatas>
              <Data id= "SE">eee</Data>
              <Data id="AD">fff</Data>
              <Data id="FR">ggg</Data>
              <Data id="DOC">hhh</Data>
            </MetaDatas>
            <Provider>
              <Name>System.Data.SqlClient</Name>
              <DataSource>10.198.164.169</DataSource>
              <Catalog>yyy</Catalog>
              <User>sa</User>
              <Password>xx</Password>
            </Provider>
        </Connexion>
    </BDD>  
</Config>
```

with this following code structure,

```
    [XmlRoot("Config")]
        public class XmlConfigBDD : XmlFileConfiguration.IXmlConfiguration
        {
            [XmlArray("Config")]
            [XmlArrayItem(typeof(DataBase), ElementName="BDD")]
            public List<DataBase> BDD { get; set; }

            public XmlFileConfiguration.IXmlConfiguration Default
            {
                get { return new XmlConfigBDD(); }
            }

            public XmlConfigBDD()
            {
                this.BDD = new List<DataBase>();
            }

            public string Path
            {
                get { return SE.Datas.Common.AppPaths.GetBddConfigurationFilePath(); }
            }
        }

        public class DataBase
        {
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Connexion")]
            public ConfigConnection Connexion { get; set; }
            public DataBase()
            {
                this.Connexion = new ConfigConnection();
            }
        }



        public class ConfigConnection
        {
            [XmlArray("MetaDatas")]
            //public ConfigMetaDatas MetaDatas { get; set; }

            public List<ConfigMetaDatas> MetaDatas { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Provider")]
            public ConfigProvider Provider { get; set; }

            protected static readonly string _Connection_ = @"metadata=res://*/%Metadata%.csdl|res://*/%Metadata%.ssdl|res://*/%Metadata%.msl;provider=%Provider%;provider connection string=""%ProviderConnectionString%""";

            public ConfigConnection()
            {
                this.MetaDatas = new List<ConfigMetaDatas>();
                this.Provider = new ConfigProvider();
            }

protected static readonly string _Metadata_TobeReplace_ = "%Metadata%";
        protected static readonly string _Provider_TobeReplace_ = "%Provider%";

        protected static readonly string _ProviderString_TobeReplace_ = "%ProviderConnectionString%";

        public string getModelConnection()
        {
            return this.getConnectionString(this.MetaDatas.Find(ctx => ctx.Id == "SOC").Value);
        }

           /*...*/
        }


        public class ConfigMetaDatas
        {
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [XmlText(Type = typeof(string))]
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public ConfigMetaDatas()
            {
            }
        }


        public class ConfigProvider
        {
            [XmlElement("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("DataSource")]
            public string DataSource { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Catalog")]
            public string Catalog { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("User", IsNullable = true)]
            public string User { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Password", IsNullable = true)]
            public string Password { get; set; }



            public ConfigProvider()
            {

            }

            /*...*/
        }
```

It doesn't work, I have tried different combinations.
The connection string returned is null.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"

Comment: Hint: *Write* the class out as XML; comparing the two XML files you see where the class definition doesn't match the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    [XmlArray("Config")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(DataBase), ElementName="BDD")]
    public List<DataBase> BDD { get; set; }
```

with:

```
    [XmlElement]
    public List<DataBase> BDD { get; set; }
```

(the original version indicates that there should be an extra `<Config>` inside the root `<Config>`)

And *because* the meta-data data *does* have a parent/child xml structure, it should be:

```
    [XmlArray("MetaDatas")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Data")]
    public List<ConfigMetaDatas> MetaDatas { get; set; }
```

Comment: It seems, it doesn't work. When I am writting it, it remains only <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Comment: @Cantinou I have tested the code with just the two changes I proposed; it works fine, including the output. Here's what I have: http://pastie.org/10983954 (note I had to hack out a few bits that don't compile from just your code, and I changed `getModelConnection` a bit because of the missing external method)

Comment: It works fine! Thank you. I don't know why it didn't work the first.